# Xcode complaining about conflicting provisioning settings

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm just trying to test 1 app on my own Iphone device (I'm NOT going to publish it to the app store) which I have exported from Unity. I have been struggling for a long time now trying to build it. Xcode complaining about conflicting provisioning settings. **I have read similar threads and followed different instructions but nothing seems to work.**
I mean already **tried to uncheck and then check again "Auto manage signing"** in Xcode and choosing the appropriate team but that doesnt help. Plese help me!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code Signing Identity -> Debug -> Any Ios SDK ==> ios Developer (I am assuming you added your device under your apps certificate)

Comment: @GokulG, did as you specified, still the same problem. However, I dont understand what you mean by adding your device under your apps certificate. On the Xcode help website it says "If you use automatic signing (recommended), Xcode creates signing certificates and provisioning profiles for you."

Comment: so when you are running on a device, we cannot simply connect device run. (1) You have to enroll in Ios developer program [https://developer.apple.com/programs/] for which we have to pay 99$ if I remember correctly. (2) Once you enrolled you have to register your app first by giving your app an app id, and (3) you have to register your device using devices UUID,  (4) and to develop  for the app you registered, you need to create a development certificate for that app, in that development certificate you have to select devices you to develop in(basically you select the device you registered)

Comment: all of this is place so that ppl wont just get code and directly start installing in their phone. But you can install in simulator you dont need any of those steps.

Comment: found an article that might help you https://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/ have a look

Comment: @GokulG All those steps were true for some time ago. Now, it's possible to sideload an app to the phone WITHOUT paying 99 USD and probably without those certificates and all that stuff. As I wrote in the thread, I don't wanna upload the app to the app store (which would cost me 99 dollars), but only to test it on my device. 
https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/27/how-to-create-free-apple-developer-account-sideload-apps/

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Cool I didnt know that. after little bit of googling, looks like ppl have faced your issue. No generic solution tho. try giving different unique bundle Identifier if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the bundle identifier, it has to be a unique name. I changed also "Company name" and "product name" and disabled "Automatically Sign" in build settings inside Unity, and then re-enabled it inside Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and select the profile and team in project and all targets.
It sometime works that way and ignores whether you have selected correct one or not.